# Hosting .NET Core on Heroku (.msproj)

Tags: c#, heroku, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I've recently finished building my first from-start-to-*sort-of*-finish MVC application in .NET **Core** which I want to host.

However the only possibility of free hosting I can find is using Heroku, which only seems to support ***earlier*** versions of .NET Core (or Visual Studio) which uses `project.json`.

As such I've been looking around online to find a way to convert my `.msproj` project to a `project.json` project.

Has anyone else encountered this, or have heard of solutions?

Comment: I don't believe you'll find a tool to migrate back to project.json but it won't be hard to do by hand. Use [the MS guide to the mapping between the two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj).

Comment: There's a lot of other free hosting offers. AWS free usage tier, for example, or [MS Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/pricing-offers/).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested yet, but try this buildpack. Its support project.json and csproj as well.

https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jenyayel/dotnet-buildpack

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Dockerfile to generate a Docker image runnable on Heroku.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet <YOUR_API_NAME>.dll
```

Then you can publish it to Heroku either directly using these Docker commands:

```
docker build -t aspnetapp <YOUR_API_NAME>
docker login --username=$HEROKU_USERNAME --password=$HEROKU_API_KEY registry.heroku.com
docker tag aspnetapp registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME/web
docker push registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME/web
```

In order these commands:

1. Create a Docker image and builds a release of your project in it
2. Connect to Heroku's docker registry using your credentials
3. Creates a new tag for your image
4. Publishes your image to your Heroku app

However, if your machine does not support Docker, you can also use CircleCI to run these commands. More details here: 
 https://www.codingnagger.com/2018/02/21/continuous-delivery/